Windows 10 "Can't connect to this network" until I "Add a new network manually", then it works fine
Whenever I try to connect to a wireless network that I haven't connected to before, my Windows 10 laptop immediately errors out with:

Can't connect to this network

However, if I go to "Manage known networks" and "Add a new network manually", it connects to the network just fine thereafter.
This happens for all new Wi-Fi networks that I try to connect to from my laptop.
Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

What's the make and model of the hardware, and also the WLAN card?

Is this behavior limited to this computer? If you use a different computer or device on these same networks, do they behave correctly, or have this same issue? Have you updated or reinstalled network drivers? Perhaps try uninstalling the network drivers/software and deleting the hardware entries from Device Manager, rebooting, then reinstalling these?

@music2myear: Yes, it's limited to this computer. I have another laptop that works just fine. I'm a little weary of uninstalling the device and reinstalling it... because if it doesn't work, I'll lose all my known networks, and will have to add them back again. Any idea if there's a way to avoid that?

You'd need to give us more information. What does Event Viewer say? What are the properties of these networks you're trying to connect to? Have you checked for and installed any and all available updates for your OS? Also, you can backup and restore known networks in Windows: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3530-how-backup-restore-wireless-network-profiles-windows-10-a.html

@music2myear: It didn't even occur to me to check Event Viewer -- which log should I check? Yeah I've updated my OS, this has been happening for a long time. There's nothing special about the networks, this literally happens for every open (i.e. password-lacking) network. And thanks for the tip, I'll see if I can back up and restore the known networks~

Start with Windows Logs > System, though a web search will give you more tips where to find that sort of stuff. Also, note that you have not yet provided the system details such as Vomit IT asked you for yesterday.

What antivirus or endpoint protection solution do you have installed? What's the WLAN card make, model, and driver version on the laptop? What is the winver of the Windows 10 OS? Have you tried "forgetting" old stale networks you no longer connect to or need if you have slews of them saved? Have you tried creating a new local account on the machine, signing on with it to see if it's isolated to just the Windows profile you normally use? What is your WLAN OS level power and other configs set to? For vague questions, you will get mainly intuitive guesses without disclosing full detail.

Have you had a chance to follow the various answers given below yet?

@music2myear: Not quite, I'm traveling at the moment. There hasn't even been an open Wi-Fi network around me for me to test against for the past few days.

Please keep in mind that you set a bounty on this and attracted answers, and being unavailable to attend to these and provide feedback doesn't leave a great taste in people's mouths regarding your question and engagement. Just something to keep in mind.

@music2myear: don't worry, if any of the answers actually solved the problem for me (assuming it's reasonable and not "wipe your OS" or such) I'm happy to come back and put another bounty to award it. But also this problem had been plaguing me earlier during my travels, which is why I posted it. I obviously don't have the problem at home with know networks...

@JoepvanSteen: You're misunderstanding the problem. I can already connect to any network just fine when it is already a known network. I can also connect fine when it is an encrypted network, even if it is unknown. It is only unknown, unencrypted networks that my computer doesn't connect to. Telling me to change the property of a known network makes no sense when the network is unknown...

Uninstall the device in Device Management then Scan for Hardware Changes to reinstall it. (If you're concerned about losing known wireless networks, you CAN backup and restore known wireless networks in Windows.)

Hey, I just had a chance to test this. Uninstalling and reinstalling the network adapter seems to have worked, thanks so much. I updated your answer to take out the portions that don't help. I'll put another bounty and give it to you when I can - please remind me in 24h.

The requested reminder.

Thank you! Done.

@music2myear any speculation on why something like that would resolve this problem?

Something messed up in the driver? I don't really know. This is just a method I've found useful for resetting network issues beyond any built-in troubleshooters (which are getting better) going back several Windows versions.

@DavidShader: I don't imagine it's related to the driver or device, but rather the fact that Windows seems to scatter system network configurations all over the place. I suspect some misconfigured part of it pertaining to the interface gets reset when you do this. And for what it's worth, I'm not actually (yet) sure if the fix is permanent. I seemed to encounter a similar issue a day or two after, but I'm not sure if that one had to do with the network I was connecting to or if it was the same problem over again. I'll have to test more later and report back if I see anything funny.

Do a network reset:
Start Menu > type 'network reset' // Should be the first option. Looks like this:


You could possibly use the "Repair" (Which in my case just seems to disable and re-enable the network adapter) by going to Control Panel->Networks and Internet->Network and Sharing center->Change Adapter settings, then right clicking on your Wi-Fi adapter and then clicking "Repair"

Have you seen this fix this problem before? Or is this just a random guess

this will sometimes fix the problem with networking issues.
